# Изображение из кусочков (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Привет. Допустим есть куски изображения (Как мозаика), нужно эти куски собрать вместе на веб-странице, чтобы можно было потом менять какие-либо куски на другие. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: я в таком виде получаю задания от начальства. Это можно сделать путем уточнения деталей и написания кода.

Comment: И что же Вам не понятно?

Comment: например - кусочки мозаики - прямоугольные или полигоны, существуют в виде серверных растров или создаются на клиенте, позиционируются относительно друг друга и страницы - исходя из каких данных, и так далее.

Comment: @Igor Ну не знаю, товарищ FreeDooM ниже, понял вопрос и помог мне.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На canvas их нарисуйте
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

Ну или более топорно - насоздавать тэгов , присвоить им нужный аттрибут src, задать абсолютное позиционирование и выстроить в нужном порядке.

Comment: Спасибо! С Canvas'ом получилось)

Comment: @freedom Проблема небольшая с Canvas'ом. Сначала отрисовал одно изображение, затем на нем отрисовал 2-e. Я так понимаю я не смогу так просто удалить 2 изображение с canvas, не попортив 1-ое?

Comment: Нужно полностью canvas перерисовывать и запихивать на него нужные куски (которые при каждой перерисовке могут отличаться)